# Loading HTML based on a parameter in the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I want to do is load a piece of HTML based on information in the url string. 
E.g. **http://examplesite.com/blah/blah/1/**

will load HTML document **/media/html/1.html** *and then*

**http://examplesite.com/blah/blah/2/**

will load HTML document **/media/html/2.html**

So far I have the script to load the HTML

```
$("#includedContent").load("/Media/html/1.html"); 
<div id="includedContent"></div>
```

and then the code to find the piece of url string I need

```
var returnPage = function() {
    var urlString = window.location.pathname;
    var stringArray = urlString.split("/");
    return stringArray[3];
};
```

I need a way of combining the two so the right webpage is finding the correct piece of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are asking, but I think you are looking for something like this:

```
$("#includedContent").load("/Media/html/" + returnPage () + ".html"); 
<div id="includedContent"></div>
```

If that's not your issue, could you provide more details?  I'm guessing what you mean by combine.

Comment: Hi there, cheers, I've tried your suggestion and the ones below to no avail.  Essentially I need to add a widget onto a page, however there are 134 pages that I need it to display on, with slightly different information to be displayed for each. I need to scale across so I don't have to add manually.  When this information is pulled through, when the user clicks on the widget it is then to display a form.  Each page has it's own id, i.e C015 which is referenced in my html file relevant to the content that needs to be displayed, which is what I am trying to pull through (unsuccessfully).

Comment: If both of your functions are working, then any of these answers should work then.  I'd check your developer console for errors, it's likely you aren't parsing the string correctly in some way.

Comment: Could there be an issues with the returnPage () function?

`var returnPage = function() {
    var urlString = window.location.pathname;
    var stringArray = urlString.split("/");

    return stringArray[3]; // number == whichever piece of the array you want to get
};

function myFunction() {
    alert(returnPage());
}`

Using the above code is the only way I've seen it working. (as an alert)

Could I be missing a function of some sort?

Comment: If http://examplesite.com/blah/blah/1/ is actually your pathname, then it will fail (returns blah).  You'd need return stringArray[5].  It's hard to debug it with fake names though, I'd try debugging through and seeing what link you are getting as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Just cobine your two js:

```
var returnPage = function() {
    var urlString = window.location.pathname;
    var stringArray = urlString.split("/");
    $("#includedContent").load("/Media/html/"+stringArray[3]+".html"); 
};
returnPage();
```